# fileUpload is undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc

buen día.

Estoy trabajando en un chat interno de un sistema y tengo un input donde adjunto un archivo pero a la hora de enviar el mensaje con el archivo, me aparece un error en la consola que dice:

> Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "files", fileUpload is
> undefined
>
> AgregarSeguimiento http://localhost:23628/:41566
>
> onclick http://localhost:23628/:1

Aquí esta el form que uso para el agregar el mensaje y el archivo

```
<form role="form">
       <div class="card-body">
          @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SolicitudId)*@
               <div hidden id="SolicitudId"></div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                         <input type="text" id="Mensaje" name="Mensaje" placeholder="Escriba su mensaje ..." class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                              <span class="input-group-append">
                                 <input type="button" value="Enviar" id="botonGuardarSeguimiento" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AgregarSeguimiento(event)" />
                                           </span>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="input-group">
                                           @*<input type="file" id="Archivos" name="Archivos" class="form-control" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.png" multiple />*@
                                       <input hidden id="btnoriginal" class="form-control text-center col-md-6" onChange="document.getElementById('tagsmall').innerText=document.getElementById('btnoriginal').files[0]['name'];" type="file">
                                       <input type="button" id="botonInput" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="document.getElementById('btnoriginal').click();" value="Adjuntar archivo">
                                        <small id='tagsmall'>No hay archivos adjuntos</small>
                                    </div>
        @*<div class="errorTxt"></div>*@
 </div>
</form>
```

Y al hacer click me manda a funcion que envia los datos del mensaje y el archivo adjunto.

```
function AgregarSeguimiento(e) {

       e.preventDefault();

       showSpinner();

       if (!$('#frmSeguimiento').valid()) {
           return false;
       }

       $('#botonGuardarSeguimiento').prop('disabled', true);

       var URL = '@Url.Action("Create", "SolicitudSeguimientos")'
       var form = $('#frmSeguimiento');
       //var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();

       //console.log(token);
       //var fileUpload = $("#files").get(0);
       //var files = fileUpload.files;

       //var formData = new FormData($("form")[0]);

       var fileUpload = $("#Archivos").get(0);
       var files = fileUpload.files;

       var formData = new FormData();
       formData.append('Mensaje', $('#Mensaje').val());
       formData.append('Archivos', $('#Archivos').val());
       var id = $('#SolicitudId').text();
       formData.append('SolicitudId', id);

       //var formElement = document.getElementById("frmSeguimiento");
       //var formData = new FormData(formElement);
       console.log(formData);


       //formData.append('SolicitudId', id);
       //formData.append('__RequestVerificationToken', token);

       //console.log('formData: ' + JSON.stringify(formData));
       $.getJSON({
           url: URL,
           data: formData,
           type: 'POST',
           processData: false,
           contentType: false,
           success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
               //alert('El seguimiento ha sido agregado');
               document.getElementById("frmSeguimiento").reset();
               $('#botonGuardarSeguimiento').prop('disabled', false);
               //hideSpinner();
           },
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               $('#botonGuardarSeguimiento').prop('disabled', false);
               //var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
               //alert(err.Message);
               console.log("error " + textStatus);
               console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);

               //alert('request: ' + request.me);
               //alert('error: ' + error);
               alert('Error al agregar la atención');
               hideSpinner();
           }
       }).done(function (data) {
           //console.log('done result 2' + result);
           console.log('done agregar seguimiento');

           console.log('inicia seguimiento');
           Seguimientos(id);
           console.log('fin seguimiento');
           $('#botonGuardarSeguimiento').prop('disabled', false);
           hideSpinner();
           setTimeout(function () { $('#Mensaje').focus(); }, 300);
       });

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noto que el archivo nunca lo pasas al adicionas al FormData, ahí un error, por otro parte, para que se capturas de buena forma el archivo, te recomiendo que lo hagas por JavaScript, a continuación el código (simplifique algunas cosas), como notaras no se envie ya ningún parámetro a la función AgregarSeguimiento, tambien esto puedes cambiarlo por un evento directamente de Jquery:

```
$("#botonGuardarSeguimiento").on('change', function(){   //codigo  }):
```

De todas formas el código JavaScript editado:

```js
function AgregarSeguimiento() {
    var URL = '@Url.Action("Create", "SolicitudSeguimientos")'

    var archivoSubido = document.getElementById("miArchivo").files[0];

    

    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("file", archivoSubido);

    $.getJSON({
        url: URL,
        data: formData,
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (resultado) {
            console.log(resultado);

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error " + textStatus);
            console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    }).done(function (data) {

        console.log('Satisfactorio');
        

    });

}
```

Por otra parte para probar este fragmento y verificar que llegue al controlador, la forma de validar es la siguiente:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create()
{

    try
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var archivoSubido = Request.Files[0];
        }

        return Json(new { mensaje = "satisfactorio" });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new { mensaje = "ERROR: " + e.ToString() });
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me sirvio mucho!!